# Mass-pasting Microsoft Excel worksheets into Microsoft Word

Tags: excel, image, excel-2010, copy-paste, word-2010

TL;DR: Need to paste mass data as image into a single doc.

Hi, I'm helping to compile monthly Management and Governance Reports consisting of 150+ pages, half of which are screenshots of 'dashboards' created in Excel 2010. Each dashboard is in its own file, located in a monthly folder on a shared drive. No sheet or file protection exists.

The current process is to open each Excel file, highlight the print area in the first sheet (usually called "Report", but not always saved as the visible sheet), copy, then paste as image into a template in Word 2010 (raw pasting would require a lot of resizing). Each image takes up exactly one A4 page in Word.
It currently takes many hours of ridiculously tedious copy-pasting, and I'd love to preserve the sanity of the poor responsible soul.
I'm not too familiar with VBA, and I've tried recording a macro to no avail.

Any suggestions?
Thanks, Alex

Comment: can you copy and paste as Excel object instead of image? http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/embed-data-sheet-from-excel-2010-to-word-document/ or the Picture option might work too as long as the Paste link option is selected.

Comment: I just tried both Object and Picture, and it pastes it far larger than the page size and requires manual resizing. Even if it worked, this method is actually even more work than simply right-click Paste Picture.I was hoping for a way to reduce mouse and keyboard clicks, or even opening every individual file. The new image doesn't need to link dynamically (in fact it would be better if it didn't)

Comment: You need a better data architecture altogether. Automating what you describe will not really make things better, just harder to maintain. Step back and rethink the approach. Copy/paste is NOT the way to go. Dynamic linking and embedding is.

Comment: I appreciate what you're saying, but in this case, dynamic embedding is not the way to go. When the existing dashboard is edited next month, we don't want that to reflect in the previous month's report; that would defeat the purpose of having a monthly project snapshot.